# Can we combine these voltage sources?

Tags: voltage, transistors, bjt, power-electronics, thevenin

In the following figure, we want to find V Thevenin. I tried combining the two 3v sources (3+3=6v due to their polarities) and applied voltage divider to find the voltage across the 150kOhm resistor which is Voc or Vthevenin, but it turned out to be 3.73 which is different than the professor's Voc. Is it because of the ground between the two voltage sources that doesn't allow us to unite them? 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it because of the ground between the two voltage sources that
>   doesn't allow us to unite them?

That is correct. Because the ground was chosen there, the top-left voltage source will apply +3V on the top side of the \$91k\Omega\$, and the bottom voltage source will apply -3V on the bottom side of the \$150k\Omega\$. So you get the following equivalent schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flH1lM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Voltages are always relative, which is why we choose a "ground" node that we will refer to as 0V. You can abuse this property and choose a "new ground" node at -3V (between R2 and V2) by adding 3V to each node voltage in the circuit.

With this "new ground", you will get the solution that you calculated (3.73V). But you should not forget to then go back to the original "ground" reference, by decreasing each node voltage with 3V again, yielding 0.73V.

Comment: Alright! MWAHHH

Answer (score 0):

> the voltage across the 150kOhm resistor which is Voc or Vthevenin

No it isn't.

You need to convert both voltage sources (in series with their respective resistors) to current sources in parallel with those resistors. Then both resistors are easily combined into one resistor (91k || 150k) and the net current flowing into this "new" value produces the equivalent voltage.

This then turns back into a voltage source in series with 91k || 150k

Comment: Thank you but I made a check for the other guy. You're rich 209k he's poor 486 heheh. xoxo